# Block a KeyPressFcn while waiting mouse action

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

My program is a question/answer task:

-participant  must press on space (keyboard) bar to play a sound
-participant must after that press  on one of the two button (mouse)
-participant  must press on space bar to play a sound
...

The problem is, I want to allow only one press on space bar, because user can press many time on space and play the sound x times.
How to block the figure1_KeyPressFcn while waiting the mouse response, and once we have the mouse response we reactivate the function ?

```
 function figure1_KeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     switch eventdata.Key
        case 'space'          
                %% processing  x task  
                %playing sounds 1000 ms
                soundsc(y,Fs);
                guidata(hObject, handles); %%// Save handles data
            otherwise
           disp('error');

    end
end


function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%processing task
guidata(hObject, handles);  %%// Save the handles data
end

function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%processing task
guidata(hObject, handles);  %%// Save the handles data
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a global flag, something like this:

```
global clicked;
clicked = true;
```

Then, on your `figure1_KeyPressFcn` function, you only call the `switch` if the user has clicked, like this:

```
global clicked;
if clicked
    switch eventdata.Key
        case 'space'          
            clicked = false;
            %% processing  x task  
            ...
    end
end
```

And on both your `pushbutton?_Callback`'s, you add this:

```
global clicked;
clicked = true;
```

To set `clicked` to `true` and allow `figure1_KeyPressFcn` to process space keys again.